# What is wrong with the href in the pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

**/users/mihir/users/[object%20Object]/file.txt**

I have the following pug file and JS code to render the pug page.  I have links for the directories and files in the path filepath, for which I am adding "users/" plus a username preceding the actual directory name or filename.  However, the link to the file or directory being displayed with a tag in the pug, has a filepath as shown above.  I don't know what's going wrong.

```
subdir.pug
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= title
    hr
    ul
        li 
            a(href='../') Go Back
        each val in listing
            li 
                a(href='users/' + user + '/' +val) !{val}
    hr
```

`res.render('subdir', { title: title + req.path, listing: fs.readdirSync(filepath), user: username })`

Full JS file:

```
const e = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('css'));
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path")
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

let users = require('./users.json');
const userIDPattern = Object.keys(users).join('|');

app.use('/', express.static('assets'));

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

const title = `Directory Listing for ${__dirname}`

/*
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  listing = fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  res.render('index', { title: title + '/', listing: listing })
})


app.get('/users/*', (req, res) => {
  console.log(userIDPattern)
  console.log(req.path)
  let user = req.query.user;
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, req.path)
  console.log(filePath)
  if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    const lstat = fs.lstatSync(filePath)
    if (lstat.isDirectory()) {
      listing = fs.readdirSync(filePath)
      res.render('subdir', { title: title + req.path, listing: listing })
    } else {
      res.sendFile(filePath)
    }
    res.render('index', { title: title + req.path })
  }
  else {
    res.status(404).render("404", { file: filePath })
  }
})
*/

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Currently in the login page")
  res.render('login');
});

/*
app.get(new RegExp(`/users/(${userIDPattern})`), (req, res) => {
  console.log("Currently in the user page")
  const username = req.params[0]; // Extract the matched ID from the URL
  console.log(username);

  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, req.path)

  listing = fs.readdirSync(filePath)
  res.render('index', { title: title + req.path, listing: listing })
});

app.get(new RegExp(`/users/(${userIDPattern})/.*`), (req, res) => {
  const username = req.params[0]; // Extract the matched ID from the URL
});

*/

app.get('/index', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Currently in the index page")
  const username = req.query.user;
  console.log(username);
  console.log(req.path)
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "users/" + username)
  console.log(filePath)
  listing = fs.readdirSync(filePath)
  res.render('index', { title: title + '/users/' + username, listing: listing, user: username })
})

app.get(/^\/users\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/.*$/, (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body;
  // Handle requests matching the regex pattern
  //console.log(req.path)
  //console.log(username)
  const filepath = path.join(__dirname, req.path)
  console.log("PATH: " + req.path)
  const stats = fs.statSync(filepath);
  console.log(stats.isDirectory());

  if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    res.render('subdir', { title: title + req.path, listing: fs.readdirSync(filepath), user: username })
  } else {
    console.log("Request to view a file")
    res.sendFile(filepath)
  }

  //res.send('Matching the pattern: /users/someUser/someFileOrDirectory');
});

app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (req.body.submit == "Submit") {
    const username = req.body.username
    const password = req.body.password
    if (username in users) {
      if (users[username] == password) {
        res.redirect('/index' + "?user=" + username)
      } else {
        res.render('error', { message: "Invalid username or password!" })
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log("We have come to signup")
    res.render('signup')
  }
});

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  res.render('signup')
});

app.post("/signupsubmit", (req, res) => {

  console.log(req.body);
  const accept = req.body.check === "on"

  if (accept) {
    console.log("Accepted terms and conditions!")
    const user = {
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    }

    if (user.username == "" && user.password == "") {
      res.render('error', { message: "You must enter a username and password!" })
    }

    console.log(user.username in users)

    if (user.username in users) {
      res.render('error', { message: "That username is already taken!" })
    }

    console.log(users)
    users[user.username] = user.password
    console.log(users)

    fs.writeFileSync('users.json', JSON.stringify(users), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      else {
        console.log("The file is updated with the given data")
      }
    });

    const directoryPath = 'users/' + user.username;

    if (fs.existsSync(directoryPath)) {
      res.redirect('/index' + "?user=" + user.username)
    } else {
      fs.mkdirSync(directoryPath)
      res.redirect('/index' + "?user=" + user.username)
    }

  } else {
    res.render('error', { message: "You must accept the terms and conditions!" })
    //res.redirect('/') // this redirects to the login page
  }
});

app.get("/users/*", (req, res) => {

})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I have done the same thing with an index.pug page, shown below, and it worked perfectly fine there.

```
html
    head
        title= title
        link(href= './styles.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
    body
        h1= title
        hr
        ul
            each val in listing
                li 
                    a(href='users/' + user + '/' +val) !{val}
        hr
```

Answer (score 2):

Given you're referring to `user.username` in your JS code, presumably you'll want

```
a(href='users/' + user.username + '/' +val) !{val}
```

in your Pug code too (since you're evidently getting an object as your `user` right now).